# How to change the font of only one application?

Tags: fonts

There's an app called JuiceSSH and it's running perfectly but whenever I change my phone's font it via themes app, JuiceSSH acts weirdly inside the terminal: weird spaces and letters show. My question is how to change the font of this app only to something default, I've tried using APK editor and it always says failed to compile, and I've no idea what should I do. Can anyone please help?

(Running Android 8.1, EMUI 8.2)

Comment: What app are you using to change the font? Is it a manufacturer specific app (e.g. Samsung)? What phone?

Comment: Themes, a system app that comes with the phone, Phone is Huawei Y9 2019.

Comment: Why don't you just contact the author of JuiceSSH and ask for a in-app font selection mechanism overriding the default system theme?

Comment: I've tried this and no hope, they're not answering and seems like this program is no longer maintained, it's just thrown there on playstore with no support

Comment: Apparently it was caused by using a non monospaced font, when I used a monospaced font on system it actually got fixed but still, I'd like to know how to set a default font on an APK.